# Does Caretheodory's extension theorem of premeasures on sigma-finite measure space give us a complete measure?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

From Folland's analysis textbook, we constructed Lebesgue-Measure using the function $F(x)=x$ and defined a pre-measure on intervals of the form $(a,b]$ and extended using Caretheodory's extension theorem. This gave us a complete measure.

Now for product measures, we also defined a pre-measure on the algebra of disjoint union of measurable rectangles, but Folland goes on to say that the product measure is usually not complete. But why is this? In both cases, we extended a premeasure using Caretheodory's extension theorem and the extension is unique since $R^n$ is sigma-finite, so why did we get a complete measure in the first case, but an incomplete measure in the second case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caratheodory's theorem gives us a measure $\mu$ defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ such that it is complete. However, sometimes, we may end up restricting $\mu$ to a smaller $\sigma$-algebra; if we do this the result need not be complete obviously (compare Lebesgue measure on the full Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, which is complete, vs Lebesgue measure on the smaller Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which is not complete). Typically for product measures (as described in Folland) we take a premeasure and use Caratheodory to give us a measure and a $\sigma$-algebra such that the measure is complete, but we often end up restricting it to the product $\sigma$-algebra, and we define the **product measure** to be the restriction to the product $\sigma$-algebra. This restriction breaks the completeness.

Comment: Thank you, After spending another 40 minutes rereading the section, I was not aware that the sigma algebra of the caretheodory extension is in fact larger than the product sigma algebra. I thought they were the same thing for some reason. Is there a simple example of some set of measure 0 in the larger algebra that is not in the produc algebra say for R x R , the product of Lebesgue measure on R?

Comment: Take a non-measurable set in the real line and take its cartesian product with a singleton. This set is not in the product sigma algebra, but it does belong  to the Lebesgue sigma algebra of the plane, with measure 0.